# Android app with xampp local database error connection

Tags: android, xampp

I have a local XAMPP and some erro happer when I try to register some account.. got this error showed down
I tried with HTTP also give me an error them I change to HTTPS, already put my IP but also give an error.
Would like to know why is this error happening and what should I do

**error**

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.readytogo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeRegist" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.readytogo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password;
    private Button btn_login;
    private TextView link_regist;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8012/android_register_login/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        link_regist = findViewById(R.id.link_regist);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
              String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

              if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                  Login(mEmail, mPass);
              } else {
                  email.setError("Please insert email");
                  password.setError("Please insert password");
              }
            }
        });

        link_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void Login(final String email, final String password) {

        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                            if (success.equals("1")){

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String name = object.getString( "name").trim();
                                    String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                            "Success Login. \n Your Name:"
                                                    +name+"\nYour Email : "
                                                    +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
package com.example.readytogo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //register
    private EditText name, email, password, c_password;
    private Button btn_regist;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_REGIST = "http://127.0.0.1:8012/android_register_login/register.php";
    //register end

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        //register
        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        c_password = findViewById(R.id.c_password);
        btn_regist = findViewById(R.id.btn_regist);

        btn_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Regist();
            }
        });
        //register end
    }
    private void Regist(){
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_regist.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals(1)) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Error! " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Error! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                })

        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Really thank you

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167054/java-net-connectexception-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-253-3-port-2468-conn) out , it might help you .

Comment: @Swati just put the firewall down and got a new error

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted) out.

Comment: @Swati just got a new error! now is about ssl? what... i did uninstall the app from emulator also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection) will `solve` above error .

Comment: @Swati i take out the https... new error

Comment: there are so many answer related to this error check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)