# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect , isConnected failed: ECONNABORTED.When it happens, the subsequent requests will be wrong

Tags: android, okhttp

I have encountered many such problems. When it happens, the subsequent requests will be wrong. Restarting the app can't solve the problem, but restarting the network can.There's a 2 percent chance of it appearing on the terminal.

Log：

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to app.shubl.com/101.37.31.235:80
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(Unknown Source:145)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(Unknown Source:190)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(Unknown Source:264)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(Unknown Source:0)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(Unknown Source:22)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:25)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:161)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:136)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:161)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:173)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:161)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:59)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:161)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Unknown Source:115)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(Unknown Source:10)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(Unknown Source:17)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to app.shubl.com/101.37.31.235 (port 80) from /10.211.37.210 (port 38281) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNABORTED (Software caused connection abort)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:273)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(Unknown Source:0)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(Unknown Source:71)
... 21 more
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNABORTED (Software caused connection abort)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.253.3 (port 2468): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167054/java-net-connectexception-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-253-3-port-2468-conn)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question may be different.It doesn't come up every time

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167152/9195139

The error is called port AND at this IP address are not ready to receive. Possible explanations are:

- the service has crashed or hasn't been started,
- your client is trying to connect using the wrong IP address or port, or
- server access is being blocked by a firewall that is "refusing" on the server/service's behalf. This is pretty unlikely given that normal practice (these days) is for firewalls to "blackhole" all unwanted connection attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question may be different.It doesn't come up every time.It happens on a user's phone. It's not easy to test