# Getting error in connecting mysql db with Android while running on mobile

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I am trying to insert data through my app from my physical android device to the mysql db. For connection I am trying to send my request to the url given below

```
String regUrl = "http://192.168.0.7:80/userInf/register.php";
```

Here, **192.168.0.7** is my Wireless LAN adapter wi-fi - IPv4 address found by using **ipconfig**.
I am getting the error in the logcat as:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.7:80
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
...
```

I had also wrote made the file in **res/xml/network_security_config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And in the mainfest I had also added :

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

please help that what to do

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167152/5566935) should help you.